# Move OnClickListener from CustomArrayAdapter to the calling class

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have LocationAdapter class with code:

```
package ru.neverdark.phototools.utils;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import ru.neverdark.phototools.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * A class provide adapter for locations
 */
public class LocationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LocationRecord> {
    private Context mContext;
    private int mResource;

    private ArrayList<LocationRecord> mObjects = new ArrayList<LocationRecord>();

    public LocationAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            ArrayList<LocationRecord> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        Log.message("Enter");
        mContext = context;
        mResource = resource;
        mObjects = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.message("Enter");
        View row = convertView;
        LocationHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);
            holder = new LocationHolder();
            holder.locationRow_image_edit = (ImageView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.locationRow_image_edit);
            holder.locationRow_image_remove = (ImageView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.locationRow_image_remove);
            holder.locationRow_label = (TextView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.locationRow_label);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (LocationHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        LocationRecord record = mObjects.get(position);
        holder.locationRow_label.setText(record.locationName);

        // TODO need change "<=" to ">"
        /* if is not current location and not point on map */
        if (position <= Constants.LOCATION_POINT_ON_MAP_CHOICE) {
            holder.locationRow_image_edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.locationRow_image_remove.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            holder.locationRow_image_edit
                    .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Log.message("Enter");
                            Log.message("Edit #" + String.valueOf(position));
                        }
                    });

            holder.locationRow_image_remove
                    .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Log.message("Enter");
                            Log.message("Remove #" + String.valueOf(position));
                            // TODO remove

                        }
                    });

        }

        return row;
    }

    static class LocationHolder {
        ImageView locationRow_image_remove;
        ImageView locationRow_image_edit;
        TextView locationRow_label;
    }
}
```

LocationRecord class:

```
package ru.neverdark.phototools.utils;

/**
 * A class contains one record from Locations table
 */
public class LocationRecord {
    public long _id;
    public String locationName;
    public double latitude;
    public double longitude;

    public LocationRecord(long _id, String locationName, double latitude,
            double longitude) {
        super();
        this._id = _id;
        this.locationName = locationName;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

}
```

And I have LocationSelectionFragment (class caller for LocationAdapter):

```
package ru.neverdark.phototools.fragments;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import ru.neverdark.phototools.R;
import ru.neverdark.phototools.utils.LocationAdapter;
import ru.neverdark.phototools.utils.LocationRecord;
import ru.neverdark.phototools.utils.Log;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockDialogFragment;

public class LocationSelectionFragment extends SherlockDialogFragment {

    private View mView;
    private ListView mListView;

    /**
     * Binds classes objects to resources
     */
    private void bindObjectsToResources() {
        mListView = (ListView) mView
                .findViewById(R.id.locationSelection_listView);
    }

    /**
     * Fills list view
     */
    private void fillData() {
        Log.message("Enter");

        ArrayList<LocationRecord> arrayList = new ArrayList<LocationRecord>();
        arrayList.add(new LocationRecord(0,
                getString(R.string.locationSelection_label_currentLocation), 0,
                0));
        arrayList.add(new LocationRecord(1,
                getString(R.string.locationSelection_label_pointOnMap), 0, 0));

        LocationAdapter adapter = new LocationAdapter(mView.getContext(),
                R.layout.location_row, arrayList);

        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.message("Enter");
        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        dialog.setTitle(R.string.locationSelection_label_selectLocation);
        return dialog;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.message("Enter");
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_location_selection,
                container, false);

        bindObjectsToResources();
        setOnItemClickListener(this);
        fillData();
        return mView;
    }
// more codes
```

How I can move OnClickListener from LocationAdapter to LocationSelectionFragment with "int position" from getView?

Comment: you need item click listener?

Comment: I need click listener for ImageView (R.id.locationRow_image_edit, R.id.locationRow_image_remove). My problem - I don't know how I can get "final int position" from getView function in class caller.

Comment: use `OnItemClickListener` and override `onItemClick` your 3rd param is the position. but this is list item click. but what's wrong with click listener in `getview`?

Comment: Not wrong. But I do not like the idea of ​​keeping most of the UI-functionality in the adapter.

Comment: why is that it has no complciations as adapter is tied to the activity

Comment: I'm not a programmer, but I think that the scheme in which the class A calls class B; class B calls class C; class C calls class A - this approach complicates the understanding of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, really.

What you CAN do is define an interface in your adapter that has methods onLocationImageEdit(int position) and onLocationImageRemove(int position) and make the calling class implement that interface. Keep a reference to the caller class, cast as the interface inside the adapter and use that for a callback.
Set the OnClickListeners the way you are doing it now, but in the listeners call the appropriate method.

Here's an example to make it a bit clearer:

```
public class LocationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LocationRecord> {
    public interface LocationImageChangeListener{
        public void onLocationImageEdit(int position);
        public void onLocationImageRemove(int position);
    }

    private LocationImageChangeListener mCallback;

    public LocationAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            ArrayList<LocationRecord> objects, LocationImageChangeListener callback) {
        ....
        mCallback = callback;
    }
    ....
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ...
        holder.locationRow_image_edit
                    .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            mCallback.onLocationImageEdit(position);
                        }
                    });
        ...
    }
}


public class LocationSelectionFragment extends SherlockDialogFragment implements LocationImageChangeListener {
        .....
    private void fillData(){
        ...
        LocationAdapter adapter = new LocationAdapter(mView.getContext(),
            R.layout.location_row, arrayList, this);
    }

    @Override
    onLocationImageEdit(int position){
           Log.message("Enter");
           Log.message("Edit #" + String.valueOf(position));
       }
    }
}
```

While a bit more verbose, this approach promotes loose coupling and allows you to use any implementation of LocationImageChangeListener in the adapter, which could be useful along the way and is generally considered a good practice in software architecture.

I wrote this freehand so it might have a syntax error or something, but I hope you get the general design of it.

Answer (score 0):

I am having trouble to understand exactly what you need.
If you want to call a method from `LocationSelectionFragment` from the `onClickListener`:

On `LocationSelectionFragment` create your method

```
public void doSomethingWithOisitionFromGetView(int position) {
    //method body
}
```

On the contructor of LocationAdapter add an argument, also hold a private variable pointing to the new argument

```
private LocationSelectionFragment lsf;

public LocationAdapter(LocationSelectionFragment lsf, Context context, int resource,
            ArrayList<LocationRecord> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.lsf=lsf;
        Log.message("Enter");
        mContext = context;
        mResource = resource;
        mObjects = objects;
    }
```

Now on your `fillData()` method of class `LocationSelectionFragment` you, instantiate adapter like this

```
LocationAdapter adapter = new LocationAdapter(LocationSelectionFragment.this, mView.getContext(),
                R.layout.location_row, arrayList);
```

Now on your `onClickListener` you can do:

holder.locationRow_image_edit
                    .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Log.message("Enter");
                        Log.message("Edit #" + String.valueOf(position));
                        lsf.doSomethingWithOisitionFromGetView(position);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Thanks, but I do not like the idea to keep a copy of the calling class in the adapter.